# Load content in a div with ajax

Tags: posts, ajax

please give me advice Im very new to ajax, I have a list of posts, if I click it will display the posts information in a div without load the page. I know I must use ajax, so I create a file: loadcontent.php in a root folder and use this code below, but I don't know how to send and get data throught ajax. I need to pass an id in order to get post infos.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $(".post-link").click(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel"); //this is the post id
        $("#post-container").html("content loading");
        $("#post-container").load("/loadcontent.php");
       return false;
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Ajax API provided by WordPress.

In first time, fix your Ajax request :

```
<script>
$(".post-link").click(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).attr("rel"); //this is the post id
    $("#post-container").html("content loading");
    $.ajax({
        url: myapiurl.ajax_url,
        type: 'post|get|put',
        data: {
            action: 'my_php_function_name',
            post_id: post_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // What I have to do...
        },
        fail: {
            // What I have to do...
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Now, you have to create your WordPress treatment. You can put this code in your functions.php or in a plugin file.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_ajax_scripts' );
function my_ajax_scripts() {
    wp_localize_script( 'ajaxRequestId', 'myapiurl', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

And then... your function that retrieve your posts

```
function my_php_function_name() {
    // What I have to do...
}
```

PS: Never put code in root install folder. Use functions.php of your theme, or create plugin. It's very important for maintainability and security. Have fun :)

Comment: Hi I got error in console : my apiurl is not defined

Comment: Do you know what might be the problem? thank you for your answer.

Comment: This is because JS does not have myapiurl in his scope... Does your ajax request works?

Comment: I recommend to you to read this doc : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
My solution is the most simplest, by not the better. Read closely this documentation and you will not have problems any more with Ajax requests in WordPress.

Comment: Try replace 'myapiurl' with 'ajaxurl'. Apparently is the default url provided by WordPress.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. It does not work yet because of that,  I include my javascript file in footer and do exactly the same above, I will try to read that.

Comment: How do you include your JS? Do you use 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action of WordPress? This doc is useful: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Hi, I use wp_enqueue_script but still get the same error myapiurl is not defined. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

The html

```
<button class="the-btn">click me</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

The js:

```
<script>
jQuery(".the-btn").click(function(){

    var param1 = 'something';
    var param2 = 'something else';

    $("div.container").html("content loading....");

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: POST, //'post|get|put'
        data: {
            action: 'my_php_function_name', 'param1':'something', 'param2':'something else'
           
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // What I have to do...
            jQuery("div.container").html(data);

        },
        fail: {
            // What I have to do...
            jQuery("div.container").html("data failed to load");
        }
    })
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Add to functions.php

```
//So, if you want it to fire on the front-end for both visitors and logged-in users, you can do this:

add_action('wp_ajax_load_my_php_function_name', 'my_php_function_name'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_php_function_name', 'my_php_function_name'); 

function my_php_function_name() {

    $param1 = $_POST['param1'];
    $param2 = $_POST['param2'];

    echo $param1." ".$param2;

}
```

If ajaxurl is not defined, which it should be, but if it'a not, add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo str_replace( array('http:', 'https:'), '', admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ); ?>';
</script>
```

More information on ajax and Wordpress:
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins